# Google search YouTube iframe errors

Tags: search, google-search, youtube-iframe-api

Some pages of my site contain youtube videos and recently I noticed they were shown with bad description.

To be exact it only shows: Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available. Click here to visit our frequently asked questions about HTML5 video.

It would be okay even if it was blank but why did it pick this thing...
Any ideas how to remove this?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I started the bounty -

Here is an example of the problem on a Google search result:

site:lifes.games

"Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available. Click here to visit our frequently asked questions about HTML5 video."

I found a website where I can view the error in some kind of browser:
https://www.websiteplanet.com/webtools/down-or-not/?DorN=http://lifes.games

[image]

The browser that site uses seems to be:

**Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KMTL, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1**

See:
https://www.websiteplanet.com/webtools/down-or-not/?DorN=https://linenum.com/browser_test.php

edit: a possible answer is:

```
if (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'googlebot') === false) {
    echo '<iframe>test</iframe>';
}
```

But I don't think I can give my own answer the bounty.